Is setting setenforce 0 equivalent to setting permissive mode in the configuration and rebooting?
Setting setenforce 0 to disable SELinux temporarily should be effective and equivalent to setting permissive mode in the configuration and rebooting.
If setenforce 0  doesn't work, it suggests that the issue might not be related to SELinux.

Yes, setting setenforce 0 to disable SELinux temporarily is as effective and equivalent to setting permissive mode in the configuration and rebooting. If setenforce 0 doesn't work, it suggests that the issue might not be related to SELinux.
Explanation:
setenforce 0 Temporarily Disables SELinux Enforcement:
This command switches SELinux from enforcing mode to permissive mode without needing a reboot. In permissive mode, SELinux logs policy violations but does not enforce them.
Editing Configuration and Rebooting:
Setting SELINUX=permissive in /etc/selinux/config and rebooting the system has the same effect as setenforce 0, making SELinux permissive from boot.
If setenforce 0 Doesn't Resolve the Issue:
If the problem persists even after setting setenforce 0, it is unlikely that SELinux is the cause. Other factors such as file permissions, Apache configuration, or file system settings (like noexec) are more likely the culprits.
Thus, using setenforce 0 is a quick and effective way to rule out SELinux as the source of the permission issue without needing to reboot the system.
Source
